# Is there a way to set up PHPBB3 to use a CAPTCHA for every post?

Tags: captcha, phpbb3

I think there is a human registering a user, getting past the original CAPTCHA, then firing his php script to spamalot.

Is there a way to make the user do the captcha test for every post in PHPBB3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't this deter regular user from using your forum ? I wouldn't use stackoverflow if I had to enter a CAPTCHA each time I wanted to post a answer...

I'm not directly answering your question, but in PHPBB 3.06 you have the "Newly Registered Users Group" to which you can give specific permissions (like all messages going to the moderation queue). May this help ? Depending on your traffic you may also validate each user manually (admin activation)

More info on PHPBB and spam here : http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1861645 (stronly suggested)

Comment: Like you said, you didn't directly answer my question, but I agree wholeheartedly with you. I've actually read that exact thread and have considered the admin activation, so no help to me, but others who might be in my position but haven't read the materials linked should definitely be directed to it, so you get the correct answer.